# Can't able to access values of gridsearch result in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe in which I couldn't able to access the values of a particular column, all the other columns are working fine. Couldn't understand why is this happening?

```
# converted the result of the grid search to a pandas dataframe
result = pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)

# the unique values of the problematic columns
result['param_regressor'].unique()
array([KNeighborsRegressor(), LinearRegression(),
       RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42),
       DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=42),
       XGBRegressor(base_score=None, booster=None, colsample_bylevel=None,
             colsample_bynode=None, colsample_bytree=None, gamma=None,
             gpu_id=None, importance_type='gain', interaction_constraints=None,
             learning_rate=None, max_delta_step=None, max_depth=None,
             min_child_weight=None, missing=nan, monotone_constraints=None,
             n_estimators=100, n_jobs=None, num_parallel_tree=None,
             random_state=42, reg_alpha=None, reg_lambda=None,
             scale_pos_weight=None, subsample=None, tree_method=None,
             validate_parameters=None, verbosity=None)], dtype=object)

# to to get the rows with condition
result[result['param_regressor']=="LinearRegression()"]
# output - empty dataframe
```

I though that the reason could be that I am making mistakes in writing the value "LinearRegression()" . So I tried to do groupby on this column.

```
# groupby on with this column
result.groupby(['param_regressor'])['mean_test_score'].mean()
# output - Error - 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'LinearRegression' and 'KNeighborsRegressor'
```

Again I am getting error when working with this column. But I am not having any problem with any other columns as you can see below.

```
# groupby on another column
result.groupby(['param_imputer__strategy'])['mean_test_score'].mean()
param_imputer__strategy
constant        -0.482673
mean            -0.482673
median          -0.482673
most_frequent   -0.482673
Name: mean_test_score, dtype: float64
```

can anyone tell me what is the reason for this?

First five rows of the data -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If *LinearRegression* wa imported like this: `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`, then I would suggest to try:

- replacing: `result[result['param_regressor']=="LinearRegression()"]`
- with: `result[result['param_regressor'].dtypes == "LinearRegression"]`

The same goes for *KNeighborsRegressor*.

Comment: I am getting an error - 
TypeError: data type 'LinearRegression' not understood.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post `result.head()` output?